# Сложная форма (массив в массиве)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, форма

Есть форма (https://jsfiddle.net/7zfjs6pw/26/) в которой можно добавлять поля. С этой формы получаем данные в JSON: https://pastenow.ru/4P5RJ

```
var programms = [];
var total_programm = 0;
$('.class').each(function(index) {
  ++total_programm;
  fd.append('programm' + index, JSON.stringify({
    'select-direction': $(this).find('.select-direction').find('li.active').text() || '',
    'select-form': $(this).find('.select-form').find('li.active').text() || ''
  }));

  var learners = [];
  var total_learner = 0;

  $('.full-order .learner_block').each(function(index) {
    ++total_learner;
    fd.append('learner' + index, JSON.stringify({
      'select-position': $(this).find('input[name="trainee_position"]').val() || '',
      'select-people': $(this).find('input[name="full_people"]').val() || ''
    }));
  });

  fd.append('total_learner', total_learner);
```

Нужно сделать что-бы массив "learner" был в массиве "programm", например, после "select-form". https://pastenow.ru/4P5SW

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Comment: "после" - имеется ввиду, "сразу же за..." или не важно на какой позиции, главное чтобы не "перед"?

Comment: Главное что-бы массив "learner" был в "programm", а в конце или вначале не важно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так:

```
var programms = [];
var total_programm = 0;
$('.class').each(function(index) {
  ++total_programm;

  $(this).addClass('total_programm_'+total_programm);

      var trainee_position = [];
      $('.total_programm_'+total_programm+' input[name="trainee_position"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
          trainee_position.push($(this).val());
        }
      });
      var full_people = [];
      $('.total_programm_'+total_programm+' input[name="full_people"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
          full_people.push($(this).val());
        }
      });

  fd.append('programm' + index, JSON.stringify({
    'select-direction': $(this).find('.select-direction').find('li.active').text() || '',
    'select-form': $(this).find('.select-form').find('li.active').text() || '',
    'select-position': trainee_position,
    'select-people': full_people,
  }));
```

Немного не то что хотел, но зато работает.